# Python. Объединение ячеек в excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Утро доброе.
Есть задача. В файле excel есть столбец с данными в ячейках. Необходимо в следующем столбце объединить эти ячейки и вписать туда сумму всех ячеек из предыдущего столбца. Какой библиотекой в python можно это сделать?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Попробуйте openpyxl

Comment: Уже пытаюсь. Но все равно спасибо за помощь. Значит я думаю что правильно выбрал библиотеку.

Answer (score 3):

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
import openpyxl


columns = ['Language', 'Text', 'Total']
rows = [
    ['python', 1],
    ['java', 2],
    ['c#', 3],
]

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()

for i, value in enumerate(columns, 1):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=i).value = value

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 2):
    for j, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        cell = ws.cell(row=i, column=j)
        cell.value = value

ws.merge_cells('C2:C4')

# Total:
ws['C2'].value = '=SUM(B2:B4)'

wb.save('excel.xlsx')
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Пример из документации по объединению ячеек](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#merge-unmerge-cells)

Comment: А может подскажите как быть с такой ситуацией. Столбец В - это время. Столбец С - это часовые показания. Столбец D - это полусуточные, которые получаются сложением часовых показаний из столбца С.
Полусуточные показания должны считаться в следующем порядке: от 15.00 ч до 3.00 ч (включительно) и от 3.00 до 15.00 включительно.
Как в коде это сделать? 
P.s.: как скриншот сюда загружать не знаю

Comment: Попробуйте сначала на самом excel'е провести сумму времени, возможно понадобится поиграться с формулами. Просто, таким не занимался и мало представляю зачем и как )

Comment: @Rashid-s, лучше открыть новый вопрос и привести в нем небольшой пример данных (в CSV формате или указать ссылку на файлообменник с Excel файлом) и пример того, что вы хотите получить в итоге. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)